# Scan aPDF file using online scanner

Tags: python, scanning

I want to scan about 1000 pdf files using "wepawet" which is an online scanner but it takes one file at a time how could I scan the whole 1000 files, could I do that using python ?

https://wepawet.iseclab.org/

could any one help me please? 
thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate the process by using python tools like selenium, mechanize or urllib(I'm not sure about urllib). Fill the form using mechanize (a simple example of filling a form and submitting)

```
    response = br.open(url)
    print response.read() 
    response1 = br.response()
    print response1.read()   
    br.select_form("form1")
    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    response = br.submit()
    print response.read()
```

and submit it as in the code. For more info on mechanize, visit http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet. Hope it works.

Comment: I have error 
ImportError: No module named heapq

Comment: Can you post the code you have used?

Comment: thae same one you gave me above=========
 from mechanize import Browser
 br = Browser()
 br.open("https://wepawet.iseclab.org/")===========
 br.select_form(name="edit_form")
 br['file'] = 'C:\Users\Test\Desktop\MultiplePages.pdf'
 br.submit()

Comment: is there a problem because I'm using windows 8

Comment: Windows 8 shouldn't be a problem for mechanize. My question is, where did heapq come from?

Comment: when I ran the program I had the following: ======      
    import urllib2, shutil
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 73, in <module>
    from urlparse import urlsplit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 119, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections.py", line 12, in <module>
    import heapq as _heapq
ImportError: No module named heapq